# How to download Google contacts from People API using C#

Tags: c#, google-people-api

I've made a WinForm that I want to access the contacts on my phone from. Everything works as it should but I can only download 90 contacts before exceeding my quota usage.
I've got just over 700 contacts.

How do I look at the list of 700? To do them at 90 contacts per minute isn't practical.

````
                string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly" };
                UserCredential credential = (await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = Properties.Settings.Default["ClientId"].ToString(), ClientSecret = Properties.Settings.Default["ClientSecret"].ToString() }, scopes, "user", default)) as UserCredential;
                var service = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Works Manager",
                });

                ContactGroupsResource groupsResource = new ContactGroupsResource(service);
                ContactGroupsResource.BatchGetRequest request = groupsResource.BatchGet();
                request.MaxMembers = 90;
                request.ResourceNames = new string[] { strGroup };
                BatchGetContactGroupsResponse response = request.Execute();

                foreach (ContactGroupResponse group in response.Responses)
                {
                    if (group.ContactGroup.MemberCount != null)
                    {
                        foreach (string s in group.ContactGroup.MemberResourceNames)
                        {
                            PeopleResource.GetBatchGetRequest peopleRequest = service.People.GetBatchGet();
                            peopleRequest.ResourceNames = new string[] { s };
                            peopleRequest.PersonFields = "names,addresses,emailAddresses";
                            GetPeopleResponse people = peopleRequest.Execute();
                            foreach (var person in people.Responses)
                            {
                                Client client = new Client();

                                if (person.Person.Names != null)
                                {
                                    client.strName = person.Person.Names[0].DisplayName;
                                }
                                if (person.Person.Addresses != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (var address in person.Person.Addresses)
                                    {
                                        Property p = new Property();
                                        p.strAddress = person.Person.Addresses[0].StreetAddress + ", " + person.Person.Addresses[0].PostalCode;
                                        client.addresses.Add(p);
                                    }
                                }
                                if (person.Person.EmailAddresses != null)
                                {
                                    client.strEmail = person.Person.EmailAddresses[0].Value;
                                }

                                clients.Add(client);

                                comboBoxClient.Items.Add(client.strName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }```
````